# Trouble with logical operators in JS

Tags: javascript, canvas, logical-operators

I'm trying to write a simple 2D platform game and I can't get my player object to double jump - or rather, I can't get him NOT to. When the up arrow or spacebar is pressed once, double jump is triggered no matter what. I am a JS newbie so I assume this has something to do with my use of logical operators, but I could be wrong. Here is the code:

```
(function() {
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
    window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    width = 500,
    height = 200,
    player = {
        x : width/2,
        y : height - 5,
        width : 5,
        height : 5,
        speed : 3,
        velX : 0,
        velY : 0,
        jumping : false,
        jumping_twice : false
    };
    keys = [],
    friction = 0.8,
    gravity = 0.3;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

function update(){
    if (keys[38] || keys[32]) {
        // up arrow or space
        if (!player.jumping) {
            player.jumping = true;
            player.velY = -player.speed*2;
            console.log("Player is jumping");
        } 
        else if (!player.jumping_twice) {
            player.jumping_twice = true;
            player.velY = -player.speed;
            console.log("Player is jumping twice");
        }
    }
    if (keys[39]) {
        // right arrow
        if (player.velX < player.speed) {
            player.velX++;
        }
    }
    if (keys[37]) {
        // left arrow
        if (player.velX > -player.speed) {
            player.velX--;
        }
    }

    player.velX *= friction;
    player.velY += gravity;

    player.x += player.velX;
    player.y += player.velY;

    if (player.x >= width-player.width) {
        player.x = width-player.width;
    } else if (player.x <= 0) {
        player.x = 0;
    }

    if (player.y >= height-player.height) {
        player.y = height - player.height;
        player.jumping = false;
        player.jumping_twice = false;
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    update();
})

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
```

Comment: I don't think thats a problem with logic operators but rather with the requestAnimationFrame calling the next update faster than you can release the jump key.

Comment: just checked it. set `keys[32] = keys[38] = false` just before `requestAnimationFrame(update)`

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `update()` runs multiple times while the jump key is held down; both conditions are met, one after the other, before you release the key. You could do the check and make the character jump in the keydown handler to work around that, but it is a better idea to keep the changes of your character in the main loop (`update()` in your case). To do so, you need an extra variable which determines whether the player can actually jump, based on the changes of key state - when the key gets released, the player can jump again or perform a double jump. You could give `player` a new property called, for example, `can_jump` and initially set it to `true`. Then you can do as follows:

```
if (keys[38] || keys[32]) {
    // up arrow or space
    if (player.can_jump) {
        if (!player.jumping) {
            player.jumping = true;
            player.velY = -player.speed*2;
            player.can_jump = false; // the player can't jump anymore until the key is released
            console.log("Player is jumping");
        } 
        else if (!player.jumping_twice) {
            player.jumping_twice = true;
            player.velY = -player.speed;
            console.log("Player is jumping twice");
        }
    }
```

And in the keyup handler:

```
if (e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode == 38) player.can_jump = true;
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5JF69/

Also, be aware that the speed of your game depends on how fast the browser performs a redraw, as you are updating your game logic using `requestAnimationFrame()`.

**EDIT:** In case the state of the spacebar and up keys doesn't need to remain "down" at all times the keys are actually held down (which doesn't in your current code), go for @lordvlad's solution. It's definitely better if you don't perform any other checks on those keys.

Answer (score 1):

@rhino is totally right about the explanation. I have another solution though. After the jump has been processed, reset the information about the jump key being pressed:

```
keys[32] = keys[38] = false;
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hah I'm actually the author of the tutorial code you're using.

All the answers are good answers, this is how I would personally do it.

```
if (keys[38] || keys[32]) {
    // up arrow or space
    if (!player.jumping) {
        player.jumping = true;
        player.velY = -player.speed*2;
        console.log("Player is jumping");
    } 
    else if(player.jumping && !player.jumping_twice) {
        player.jumping_twice = true;
        player.velY = -player.speed;
        console.log("Player is jumping twice");
    }
    keys[38] = keys[32] = false;
}
```

I would just set the keys to false if they are true in the check itself.

@lordvlad makes a good point, there should be an update cycle separate from the rendering, however for the purpose of the tutorial it was really just to get the user up and running to get something on the screen. At some point I'll make a part 3 to break the logic out a bit more. Anyway hope this helps.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/KFmty/)**

Comment: You have linked to my demo, is this a mistake? I think so. :D Besides, I believe the `player.jumping` check in `else if` is unnecessary, since `else if` assumes the previous condition has not been met (so it implicitly does the same that you have done).

Comment: @rhino no I'm saying if the player isn't jumping do the first condition. The else if is if the player *is* jumping, but player jumping twice hasn't been set. If you check the fiddle it works fine.

Comment: Yes, but since `if` checks whether `player.jumping` is false, the `else if` (note the `else` keyword), assumes it is true (the first check, `!player.jumping`, has failed, so `player.jumping` must be true, there is no need to test for that). It is unnecessary to perform that check, because it is already done implicitly by the JavaScript implementation. I don't mean to remove the other condition, `!player.jumping_twice`, it should be left as is. Anyway, your answer still links to my demo, not yours.

Comment: @rhino I was confused at to what you were saying, I thought you were saying it wouldn't work. I like to be overly verbose sometimes in my answers. The if/else check when someone reads it there is no doubt whats happening, the `jumping` could be removed but I think its a moot point in terms of readability and incurs no performance cost. I also updated the link that was a mistake :P